# Compilar y ejectuar archivo .java desde CMD

Tags: java, cmd

si creo mi archivo .java puede compilarlo, pero a la hora de ejecutarlo me da el siguiente error.Al ver este error pense que tendria desactualizado el java rte pero al ir a actualizarlo a la consola de JAVA me pone que se encuentra en la ultima version. Si alguien sabe como solucionarlo se lo agradecerai mucho![image: ![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF3ys.png)

Comment: La versión del compilador es 13 y la del runtime es 8. Corrige la ruta de java para que apunte al directorio de la versión 13.

Comment: Probablemente tiene más de uno java.exe en el disco.  Puede revisar PATH para ver donde estén.